# how to keep changing the background image of mdi form?

Tags: vb6

I am doing a project in vb6..i want to know how to keeping changing the background image of the MDI for as soon as it is loaded.

i tried to make an array of images and then set the timer
here is my code

```
Private Sub Timer1_Timer()
    For i = 0 To 2
        Picture1.Picture = LoadPicture(arr(i))
        i = i + 1

        If i = 3 Then
            i = 0
        End If
    Next i
End Sub

Private Sub MDIForm_Load()
    arr(0) = "images\Shop.jpg"
    arr(1) = "images\Display1.jpg"
    arr(2) = "images\Display2.jpg"
end sub
```

please help
thank you

Answer (score 0):

Couple of issues with your code as written.  First, you don't need to use a picturebox, the MDI form should have a Picture property you can set directly.

Second, as written you're cycling through all the images in your array each time the timer event fires.  What you really want is one change per timer event and store/increment the array index at the end of each timer event, like so:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Timer()
    MDIForm.Picture = LoadPicture(arr(arrIndex))
    If arrIndex + 1 <= UBound(arr) Then
        arrIndex = arrIndex + 1
    Else
        arrIndex = 0
    End If
End Sub

Dim arrIndex as Integer

Private Sub MDIForm_Load()
    arr(0) = "images\Shop.jpg"
    arr(1) = "images\Display1.jpg"
    arr(2) = "images\Display2.jpg"
    arrIndex = 0
end sub
```

The Dim of arrIndex should be at the top of your MDIForm. This will change the background picture every time the timer event fires.

Comment: You'll need to modify it slightly based on the name of your MDI parent form.  On the line MDIForm.Picture, change MDIForm to the name of your MDI parent, or Me.